# When I try to update my system it keeps telling me

Tags: system-installation, upgrade, updates, update-manager, downloads

E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu impish Release' does not have a Release file.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/micahflee/ppa/ubuntu impish Release' does not have a Release file.

Answer (score -1):

The PPA you added doesn't support Ubuntu 21.10 and should be removed.

It supports only Ubuntu 18.04 and Ubuntu 20.04. Please read the instructions here: [https://launchpad.net/~deadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa](https://launchpad.net/%7Edeadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa)